# unable to submit form data using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i am very new to php and have no idea of javascript, have done all js work using tutorials.Also tried to use existing solutions from stackoverflow, but no success !

What i am trying to do is trying to update database values using 'submit' button on the basis of values called from 'select option'.

Problem is that no data is getting updated in DB after i click on submit button ***(on viewtest.php)***, I have also tried to add the 'update.php' to form action.

Here's the screenshot of viewtest.php
[image]

here's my code:

**viewtest.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <table border="1px"><tr> <td>
<select required name="tstname" id="test" onChange="fetch_ques()">
<option> Select Test Name</option>
<?php
$res=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from test_detail");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row["test_name"]; ?>"> 
<?php echo 
$row["test_name"]; echo' - - ['. $row['test_category'].']'; ?> </option>

    <?php
            }
    ?>
    </select>
    </div>

<td>    
<div id="qnos"><select></select></div></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
 <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="vform" value="Update Question"> </td></tr>
</form>
</table>
<div id="ques"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch_ques()
 {
 var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getq.php?
 tstnm="+document.getElementById("test").value,false); // function id
 xmlhttp.send(null);
 document.getElementById("qnos").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  // div id
 }

 function display_ques()
 {
 var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET","displayq.php?
qnos="+document.getElementById("quesdd").value,false);
 xmlhttp.send(null);
 document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }

   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
   $("#vform").submit(); (function()
   // document.getElementById("vform").submit();(function()
   {
   location.href='update.php?

qno='+$("#quesno").val()+'&qn='+$("#ques").val()+'&c1='+$("#a1").val()+'&c2='+$
 ("#a2").val()+'&c3'+$("#a3").val()+'&c4='+$("#a4").val()+'&cr='+$("#cr").val();
       });
       });
       </script>


   <?php 
   if(isset($_GET['st']) && $_GET['st'] !== "")
    {
    echo"updated";      
    }
    else echo "Error: ".mysqli_errno();
    ?>
```

**displayq.php**  //Used to fetch data in select menu

```
 <?php
 include '../connect.php';
 $quesno=$_GET["qnos"];

 if($quesno!="")
 {
 $qry=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from quesadd where quesid='$quesno'");

echo "<table name='ques'>";
while($ftc=mysqli_fetch_array($qry))
{ 
?>

 <form method="POST" action="">
 <table name="ques">
 <tr><td align="center" colspan="2"> <!-- // Comment <input type="submit" name="submit" id="upq" value="Update Question">--></td> </tr>
 <tr> <td align="center"> <b> Question : <input type="text" id="quesno" value="<?php echo $ftc["quesid"];?>" disabled></b></td> 
 <td> <textarea name="ques" id="ques" cols="100" rows="3" placeholder="Please Input The Question Here !"> <?php echo $ftc['ques'];?></textarea> </td> </tr>
 <tr> <td width="25%" align="center" colspan="2"> <br> <b>Choices</b> </td> </tr>
 <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2"><b>1.</b> <input type="text" id="a1" name="a1" value="<?php echo $ftc['c1'];?>"> </td> </tr>
 <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2"><b>2.</b> <input type="text" id="a2" size="20px" name="a2" value="<?php echo $ftc['c2'];?>"> </td> </tr>
 <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2"><b>3.</b> <input type="text" id="a3" size="20px" name="a3" value="<?php echo $ftc['c3'];?>"> </td> </tr>
 <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2"><b>4.</b> <input type="text" id="a4" size="20px" name="a4" value="<?php echo $ftc['c4'];?>"> </td> </tr>
 <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2"><b><font color="maroon">Correct Answer</font></b> <input type="text" size="20px" id="cr" name="correct" value="<?php echo $ftc['answer'];?>"> </td> </tr>

</table>
</form>
 <?php
 }
 echo "</table>";
 }
 ?>

 </tr> </td> 
 </table>
 </form>
```

**update.php**  //Used to update question by getting values from 'viewtest.php'

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';
$qn=$_GET['qno'];
$qname=$GET['qn'];
$a1=$GET['c1'];
$a2=$GET['c2'];
$a3=$GET['c3'];
$a4=$GET['c4'];
$acr=$GET['cr'];

 $update=mysqli_query($connection,"update quesadd SET ques='$qname', 
c1='$a1',c2='$a2',c3='$a3',c4='$a4',answer='$acr' where quesid='$qn' ");
 if($update==true)
 {

    header('location:viewtest.php?st=true');
 }
?>
```

Comment: your form is using `POST` and in your `PHP` you are using `GET`.

Comment: yeah, that's because he's concocting a string and sending it (or trying to) via javascript... OP: read up on AJAX. Please. Pretty please. With sugar on top.

Answer (score 0):

I can see multiple problems, don't know if all the problems will go away but it will help.

`$("#vform").submit(); (function()`

The line above says if a `<form>` with the `id="vform"` has been submitted, execute this function. Your form does not have an id so it will never trigger. One other problem is that the function is not part of the trigger. It should be something like

`$("#vform").submit(function()`

The complete code could look like:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#vform").submit(function(e){
                   e.preventDefault();
                   location.href='update.php?qno='+$("#quesno").val()+'&qn='+$("#ques").val()+'&c1='+$("#a1").val()+'&c2='+$("#a2").val()+'&c3'+$("#a3").val()+'&c4='+$("#a4").val()+'&cr='+$("#cr").val();
                   return false;
               });
           });
       </script>
```

Comment: @SarfarazAnsari Is the user redirected to the `update.php` page? You can test this by removing the `header(...);` function. You should end up with an emtpy white page. Also, did you add the id to the `<form>` tag?

Comment: the submit button is not taking the page to' update.php' , its just refreshing the 'viewtest.php'.

Comment: It should be.... `location.href` changes the page your on. In your case to `update.php`. In `update.php` you tell it to get you back to `viewtest.php`. The fact that it does "refresh" tells me the redirect is working. Can you post a picture of the table `quesadd`?

Comment: Now i read your comment again I got an idea what might be going on. Leaving action empty loads the same page. I'll updated the code above to  address this.

Comment: i commented the header line in 'update.php' in this case it should redirect to 'update.php' and not revert back to 'viewtest.php'.  I have checked the database queries. here's an image - http://img04.imgland.net/h7MeOSu.png

Comment: i appreciate your effort, but still no success.

Comment: Hmm all seems fine... You can try echo'ing all values and see if they match what you espect. Also check the url when your at the `update.php` page. Are all values present and what you espect them to be?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AJAX` to submit your form and refresh/redirect the page with javascript.

**viewtest.php**

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select required name="tstname" onchange="display_ques()" id="test">
                    <option> Select Test Name</option>
                    <?php
                    $res = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from test_detail");
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row["test_id"]; ?>">
                            <?php echo
                            $row["test_name"];
                            echo ' - - [' . $row['test_category'] . ']'; ?> </option>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="qnos">
                    <select>
                        <!-- put code here for showing question id/number -->
                    </select></div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="vform" value="Update Question"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div id="ques"></div>
<h1 id="status"></h1>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function display_ques() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "displayq.php?qnos=" + document.getElementById("test").value, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }

    function fetch_ques() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getq.php?tstnm = " + document.getElementById("test").value, false); // function id
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById("qnos").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;  // div id
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#vform').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $('form#update').serialize();
            $.post('update.php', data, function (response) {
                // response is the data returned from php echo json_encode(['results' => true/false]), from update.php
                var res = JSON.parse(response);
                if (res.results == true) {
                    $('#status').html('Data was updated');
                } else {
                    $('#status').html('Error occured while trying to update data.');
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have given your `form` and `id` to be able to serialize it using `jQuery` and I have also added a hidden input to hold the id of the current question.

**displayq.php**

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';
$quesno = $_GET["qnos"];

if($quesno != "") : ?>
    <form id="update" method="POST" action=""> <!-- added an id to the form -->
        <table name="ques">
    <?php
    $qry = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from quesadd where quesid='$quesno'");
    while($ftc = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)) : ?>

                <tr><td align="center" colspan="2"> <!-- // Comment <input type="submit" name="submit" id="upq" value="Update Question">--></td> </tr>
                <tr> <td align="center"> <b> Question : <input type="text" id="quesno" value="<?php echo $ftc["quesid"];?>" disabled></b></td>
                    <td> <textarea name="ques" id="ques" cols="100" rows="3" placeholder="Please Input The Question Here !"> <?php echo $ftc['ques'];?></textarea> </td> </tr>
                <!-- added this hidden input to hold the question number -->
                <input type="text" id="quesno" name="quesno" value="<?php echo $ftc["quesid"];?>" hidden>
                <tr> <td width="25%" align="center" colspan="2"> <br> <b>Choices</b> </td> </tr>
                <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2"><b>1.</b> <input type="text" id="a1" name="a1" value="<?php echo $ftc['c1'];?>"> </td> </tr>
                <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2"><b>2.</b> <input type="text" id="a2" size="20px" name="a2" value="<?php echo $ftc['c2'];?>"> </td> </tr>
                <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2"><b>3.</b> <input type="text" id="a3" size="20px" name="a3" value="<?php echo $ftc['c3'];?>"> </td> </tr>
                <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2"><b>4.</b> <input type="text" id="a4" size="20px" name="a4" value="<?php echo $ftc['c4'];?>"> </td> </tr>
                <tr> <td align="center" colspan="2"><b><font color="maroon">Correct Answer</font></b> <input type="text" size="20px" id="cr" name="correct" value="<?php echo $ftc['answer'];?>"> </td> </tr>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then in your `update.php` you can access the values using `$_POST`

```
<?php

include '../connect.php';

$qn = trim($_POST['quesno']);
$qname = trim($_POST['ques']);
$a1 = trim($_POST['a1']);
$a2 = trim($_POST['a2']);
$a3 = trim($_POST['a3']);
$a4 = trim($_POST['a4']);
$acr = trim($_POST['correct']);

$sql  = "update quesadd SET ques='$qname', c1='$a1',c2='$a2',c3='$a3',c4='$a4',answer='$acr' where quesid='$qn'";
if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    // returning data to jQuery, as response
    // jQuery will parse this as json {results: true}
    echo json_encode(['results' => true]);
} else {
    // returning data to jQuery, as response
    // jQuery will parse this as json {results: false}
    echo json_encode(['results' => false]);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, its not working, some of the parts are not understandable by me. like
what do i add in place of redirect and failure..

one more question is, in the first part of code how are you taking the values of the form in displayq.php to update.php, i mean i cannot see any variable passing the values, may be i am a stranger to json thats why :) 

`code`
if (res.result == true) {
            // redirect
            }else {
             // failure
            }

Comment: @SarfarazAnsari can you please share your tables schema.

Comment: post `test detail` too

Comment: the `qnos` select is empty

Comment: but it is been called from another php page via ajax ?